# Why I can't insert anymore negative values to the right content inset of a UIButton?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I'm trying to add a left and right margin to the content of a UIButton. I've always managed to to that with the previous version of Xcode by adding positive values to both left and right insets (lets say 8 for both) and by adding a positive left inset (lets say 8) and a negative one (-8) for the right inset of the Title (I've attached an image to clarify what I mean).

Unfortunately I've recently tried to do the same with the last version of Xcode but I can't anymore put negative values to Right Inset field.
Have you noticed the same? Is this an Xcode issue or is a "feature" and I have to change the approach?

Thank you for your help :)

[image]

Comment: still a bug in Xcode 11, 4 years have passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Xcode. Try to set negative value by clicking stepper button on the right side of field. The value will not change, but you will see changes directly in xib. Then just close and reopen your project and you will see correct negative value.

[image]

Tested on the latest version of Xcode (7.1)

Comment: This is clearly a bug, please take a few minutes to dupe http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4985006590001152 rdar://35048527 so this gets fixed. Thanks!